# Android HorizontalScrollView перевести скролл к элементу

Tags: android, horizontalscrollview

Я использую - HorizontalScrollView.
В нем динамически созданный список RadioButton. Какой то из них включен, я точно не знаю какой именно.

Мне надо перемотать скролл в такое положение, чтобы данный RadioButton был виден для пользователя.

Можно определить виден ли конкретный View на экране и проматывать скролл пока он не попадет в зону видимости пользователем.
Возможно есть готовые решения для этого?

Если нет, то как определить, виден ли конкретный View на экране?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private final void focusOnView(){
        new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                view.scrollTo(0, view.getBottom());
            }
        });
    }
```